# Android Emulator Window Issue

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am having an issue with the android emulator on android studios. The screen of the emulator does not fit in the window. As well as this all clicks respond as if it was fit to the large window. As far as I can tell, changing any of the AVD settings have had no effect on helping it.

[image: Screenshot of the emulator]

Comment: Maybe the emulator is showing the real screen size of a nexus 5x?
If i place my nexus 5x in front of a 24" screen it looks similar to what your screenshot shows.

Comment: I changed the resolution of the displayed device and that fixed the sizing for me. However, now when I press the rotate buttons, the screen flips to the side but does not change (if that makes sense its the equivalent of if the screen was locked in the vertical position)